# pandas reducer like method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm familiar with the `JavaScript` reducer method, and I'm trying to accomplish something similar with a `DataFrame`.

I believe in the method shown below I violate the guidance  described in pandas.

`You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.`

```py
def use_reducer():
    """reducer"""
    df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'Thresh': 'SOME', 'A': 1},
        {'Thresh': None, 'A': 20},
        {'Thresh': None, 'A': 12},
        {'Thresh': None, 'A': 12},
        {'Thresh': None, 'A': 80, }
    ])

    def reducer(index):
        this = df.loc[index]
        # first row by detfault has a thresh
        if this['Thresh'] == 'SOME':
            return df.loc[index, :]
        # last row with soem threshold crossed
        some = df.loc[df['Thresh'] == 'SOME'].iloc[-1]
        # if a threshold is crossed update thresh, this row becomes the next `some`
        if (some.A < this.A):
            df.loc[index, 'Thresh'] = 'SOME'

        return df.loc[index, :]

    [reducer(index) for index in df.index]

    print(df)
```

### Out

```
  Thresh   A
0   SOME   1
1   SOME  20
2   None  12
3   None  12
4   SOME  80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient (and more pandas-esque :) solution would be to use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df.loc[df['A'].ge(df['A'].cummax()), 'Thresh'] = df['Thresh'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Thresh   A
0   SOME   1
1   SOME  20
2   None  12
3   None  12
4   SOME  80
```

Comment: thanks. I'll have to look into that.  The problem I'm run into is in the solution I am trying to implement,  There are several more statements I need to apply. Upwards of 10 conditionals. Comparing `this` vs `SOME` to determine if `this` should equal `SOME`

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, how about you ask that in a new question? Lots of folks here on SO can help with complex problems like that :)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274333/pandas-conditions-across-rows-and-columns here is full code that I want to consolidate into a single reducer like method.